# remove write protection for sd card in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sd-card

i have some SD cards that them write protection buttons are lost. each time i connecting these cards to my PC and want to copy some files to that, windows shows write protection message. I'm seeking for a software fix that permanently fix write protection problem. is there any way to remove write protection from my SD cards?

Comment: You can use a easy hardware fix. The switch on the card connect to nothing inside the card, it just trigger a hardware switch in the reader. You can put a sticky tape over the switch position, then it will appear unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixable using the command-line `diskpart` partitioning tool.

- run an elevated command prompt
- run `diskpart`
- get a list of your volumes: `list volume`, identify the sd card
- `select volume #` with # being the volume number of the sd card
- try to remove the write protection using `attributes disk clear readonly`

Comment: that not working. again write protected msg

Answer (score 0):

that above is almost right, I tried instead:

- list **disk**
- select **disk** #
- attributes **disk** clear readonly

and it worked well, my SD-Card is now unproteced

To see what es is set try:

- list disk
- attributes disk

regards J.B.